# Why can't I create a csv file with the csv module?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write a list to a csv file.
the following code runs and returns no error, but it doesnt work, in that it doesnt actually populate the csv file with the stuff in the list. I am probably doing it wrong because I don't understand something.

```
import newspaper
import os
from newspaper import article
libya_newspaperlist = []
libya_newspaper=newspaper.build('https://www.cnn.com',    memoize_article=False)
for article in libya_newspaper.articles:
libya_newspaperlist.append(article.url)
import csv
os.chdir("/users/patrickharned/")
libya_newspaper.csv = "/users/patrickharned/libya_newspaper.csv"
def write_list_to_file(libya_newspaperlist):
  """Write the list to csv file."""

    with open("/users/patrickharned/libya_newspaper.csv") as outfile:
            outfile.write(libya_newspaperlist)
```

So I changed the code to this. 
    import newspaper
    import os
    from newspaper import article
    libya_newspaperlist = []
    libya_newspaper=newspaper.build('https://www.cnn.com',     memoize_article=False)
    for article in libya_newspaper.articles:
        libya_newspaperlist.append(article.url)
    import csv
    os.chdir("/users/patrickharned/")
    libya_newspaper.csv = "/users/patrickharned/libya_newspaper.csv"
    with open("/users/patrickharned/libya_newspaper.csv", "w") as outfile:
            outfile.write(str(libya_newspaperlist))

now it does output to the csv file, but it only outputs the first entry and wont do the rest. any suggestions?

Comment: The only command that writes to the file is inside a function that you never call.

Comment: Perhaps see this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.writer)?

Comment: You should be getting a meanfull exception from the `outfile.write(libya_newspaperlist)` line (assuming you call the `write_list_to_file()` function somewhere. What does the error message say? Please [edit] your question and add it.

Comment: Okay Prune was correct I didnt properly calll the function so i got rid of the function. now I get this error message.   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/patrickharned/Documents/LibyaNewspaperFEB2.py", line 12, in <module>
    outfile.write(libya_newspaperlist)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list I think i know how to fix it can i just put str(libya_newsaperlist)?

Comment: @Harned have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 3):

You have to open the file in write mode:

```
with open("/users/patrickharned/libya_newspaper.csv", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(libya_newspaperlist)
```